# Toggle between div is not working in PHP. Without toggle it is working fine

Tags: php, html

Here I am trying to toggle the divs (divVD,divQuality,divSCM) using `$type` I.E  if `$type = vd` it should show only divVD and not others and so on..

everything works fine before going to toggle feature. as soon as i put php among divs it shows nothing as output. Can any1 let me know what i am missing here.

```
<?php
session_start();
$namex = $_SESSION['uname'];
 require "C:/xampp/htdocs/db.php";
$resultxx =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT type from members WHERE email= '$namex'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultxx)) {
echo $type = $_SESSION['typeOfUser'] = $row['type']."<br>";
}

if(isset($_POST['textinput'])){
    if(empty($_POST['textinput'])||empty($_POST['email_id'])){
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Some fields are missing";
header("location: /vms/addvendor.php");}
    elseif(preg_match("/([%\@!^&*$#\*]+)/",$_POST['textinput'])){
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Invalid characters in name";
        header("location: /vms/addvendor.php");
    }
    /* elseif (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/", $_POST['email_id'])){ 
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Email Id should be 10 characters long.";
        header("location: /vms/addvendor.php");
        } */
    else{
        $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','avl');
        $var = $_POST['email_id'];
        $check = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM scores WHERE email = '$var'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($check)!=0){
            $_SESSION['error']="Vendor Alrerady Exists";
            header("location: /vms/addvendor.php");
        }
        }

}
?>

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GOI VMS</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="\vms\index.php">Authorized Vendor List</a></li>
      <li class= "active"><a href="/vms/addvendor.php">Add Vendor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="/logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<?php if ($type == "VD"){?>

<form id = "test" action="/scores/actionpage.php/" method ="POST">
<div id="divVD" class = "container" style= "display:block">
  <h2>Vendor Development</h2>
  <p>In this section we try to check if the vendor have right infra available at his site</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Infrastructure</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    <table>
    <h3>Capacity Mapping</h3>
  <tr><td>Types of casting facility, machines & tools available with the vendor  </td><td><input type="text" name="cm1" required> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Number of moulds and capacity of the moulds with the vendor</td> <td><input type="text" name="cm2" required></td> </tr>
  <tr><td>Source of Raw material and Boughtout parts </td><td><input type="text" name="cm3" required></td> </tr>
  <tr><td>Type of Infra support system to support the entire production unit  </td><td><input type="text" name="cm4" required></td> </tr>
    </table>
    <table><h3>Capability Mapping</h3>
    <tr><td>Verify skill matrix of the operator to check if he has performed similar task in the past.</td><td><input type="text" name="cm5" required></td> </tr>

  </table>
  </div>
  <button type="button" name= "btn_vd " class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">Design & Development</button>
  <div id="demo1" class="collapse">
    <table>
  <tr><td>An experienced team in Design and Development to check the feasibility of the drawings and follow APQP process  </td><td><input type="text" name="dd1" required> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Right set of softwares to help in checking the feasibility of the drawing (if applicable)</td> <td><input type="text" name="dd2" required></td> </tr>
  </table>
    </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">Cost</button>
  <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>At what price is the product being offered by the vendor do analysis based on the costing norms set by GOR mark up analysis) and as per industry norms also
</td><td><input type="text" name="c1" required> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3">Size of the Org</button>
  <div id="demo3" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>The organisation should be financially sound and keen to work for GOR </td><td><input type="text" name="soto1" required> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4">Quality Systems</button>
  <div id="demo4" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>Which quality system does the vendor follow , Systems and Procedures  </td><td><input type="text" name="qs1" required> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>RCA of the defects generated during production and also reported by the existing clients and traceability identification of the Lot </td><td><input type="text" name="qs2" required> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Incoming / Outgoing material check sheets , Internal audits for FIFO</td><td><input type="text" name="qs3" required> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo5">CCRS</button>
  <div id="demo5" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>A dedicated team that handles customer complaints and resolution time to resolve the issues reported by the cleint</td><td><input type="text" name="ccrs1" required> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo6">Processes</button>
  <div id="demo6" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>Complete flow chart for manufacturing processes (specially for GOR required processses)</td><td><input type="text" name="p1" required> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Testing facility - Inhouse /Out-sourced - records for the same to be checked for the current clients</td><td><input type="text" name="p2" required> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo7">Logistics Facility</button>
  <div id="demo7" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>Schedule Management , Logistic facility available is inhouse/outsourced </td><td><input type="text" name="lf1" required> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
<input type="Submit" name = "submit"/>  </div>
</form>

<?php
}
elseif($type == "Quality" ){


 ?>

<div class="container" id= "divQuality" style= "display:none">
  <h2>Quality</h2>
<p>In this we check if the vendor has the right quality systems laid down which ensure that the material will be of good quality and will be defect free and in case a defect arises the vendor will do the anaysis and try to close it.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demox">QMS</button>
  <div id="demox" class="collapse">
    <table>
  <tr><td>Which quality system does the vendor follow , Systems and Procedures (ILO-Incoming /Line/ Outgoing reports from latest consignments) </td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demoX1">Availablity of Process flow</button>
  <div id="demoX1" class="collapse">
    <table>
  <tr><td>Complete flow chart for manufacturing processes vendor is expert at (specially for GOR required processses)</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Special focus on casting finish , dimensional accuracy , mechanical properties (hardness , tensile & impact test) , chemical comp for any of the existing parts vendor is manufacturing and is in running production</td> <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td> </tr>
  <tr><td>Destructive testing (if applicable) , no roughness , sand holes , blow holes , surface shrinkage . mis runs should not be there </td> <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td> </tr>
  </table>
    </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demox2">Samples</button>
  <div id="demox2" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>The vendor should have Golden / Standard samples available as per drawing, based on this vendors adherence to Drawing will be evaluated .
</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demox3">History Management</button>
  <div id="demox3" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>Record of check sheets should be there(ILO+Development Reports + Layout Inspection reports(FAI)+PPAP)  </td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Adherence to process flow  </td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demox4">Drawing Change Mgt.</button>
  <div id="demox4" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>Record of all the drawings (new+old) and information flow mechanism  </td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demox6">Calibration
</button>
  <div id="demox6" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>All the equipments should be timely calibrated </td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>There should be a plan for the same specifying the due dates for caliberation of all the equipments  </td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demox7">Storage</button>
  <div id="demox7" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>Optimum storage facility as per stored material requirement , FIFO.</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demox8">4M Mgt</button>
  <div id="demox8" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>No changes can be carried out in 4M without taking prior approval from client .</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demox9">Defect's RCA</button>
  <div id="demox9" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>Anaysis of the problems arising ,Closure of the problem and informing the stakeholders about the changes done, SCAR & adherence.</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demox10">Reliablity</button>
  <div id="demox10" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>Testing facility should be available- inhouse / outsourced mechanical / chemical testing labs , (NABL ACCREDIATED ) and records for the same should be available (X-Ray, spectroscope, Tensile strength, Elongation, Hardness).</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demox11">Tracablity</button>
  <div id="demox11" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>Tracebility of al the lots produced & dispached .</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demox12">Packaging & Dispatch</button>
  <div id="demox12" class="collapse">
    <table><br>
  <tr><td>Tracebility of al the lots produced & dispached .</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  </table>
    </div>

</div>

<?php
}


elseif ($type == "SCM"){


?>


<div class="container" id= "divSCM" style = "display:none">

  <h2>SCM Prespective</h2>
<p>In this section we try to evaluate if the vendor will be able to deliver the right product to us at the right time.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demoxx">General</button>
  <div id="demoxx" class="collapse">
    <table>
  <tr><td>Possible Transit time for material from Domestic Vendor? </td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Whether vendor is having Raw Material Test Certificates ? </td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does Vendor has Vendor selection process of their vendors ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Total No. of Major OEM Clients ? </td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does Vedor has any record of PPC in plant from last 6 months</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does Vendor has any ERP Process ? </td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does Vendor keeping record of customer's feedback ? If, Yes then any action on those feedbacks ? </td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>What is the mode of communication from top management to shop floor employee ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>What is the turnover in last financial year ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Is Vendor Using FIFO for his Raw Material inventory ? </td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Is vendor using standard packing of material ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does vendor have Skill matrix of his shop floor employees ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does Vendor has defined place for RM, FG, SFG or Rejected Material ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does vendor has defined process for Internal rejected material ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does Vendor provide prompt and technical assistance to his customer, which helps in price reduction or quality improvement or lead time reduction ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does Vendor has defined process for handling customer complaints ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does Vendor has any process for handling ECN ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does Vendor has defined subcontracting process ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does Vendor has capability to increase the shifts ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does Vendor put identification on parts before dispatching ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Does vendor has defined SOP or Work Instructions ?</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"> </td></tr>
  </table>
  </div>

  <?php }     ?>


</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You are appending `."<br>"` to `$type`. You need to remove that.

Comment: that should be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider your line

```
echo $type = $_SESSION['typeOfUser'] = $row['type']."<br>";
```

is for testing purpose. If it is not, you should remove `<br>`. then you need to go as below.

You need to remove condition blocks and add that condition to style attribute only.

i.e.

```
<div id="divVD" class = "container" style= "<?php echo ($type == 'VD')?'display:block':'display:none'; ?>" >

<div class="container" id= "divQuality" style= "<?php echo ($type == 'Quality')?'display:block':'display:none'; ?>" >

<div class="container" id= "divSCM" style= "<?php echo ($type == 'SCM')?'display:block':'display:none'; ?>" >
```

In your example, When your PHP conditions run, it doesn't load other divs. Thus you're not getting toggle worked. For that, you need to load all divs with display none or block.

By removing your condition blocks and add to that style attribute. then your jquery for toggle will work perfectly!!

Comment: It is working ... thanks bro ... i realized <br> was ruining this. But

Comment: When i was trying to do this before it was taking div till style only and php code block was not closing dont know why... .and secondly what echo did in code block can you explain?

Comment: did you checked type as output and then validated with block?

Comment: echo prints the correct style as per the condition. I went through your code and got that you're getting only one div and for toggle, you need all three divs. and just suggested you accordingly. If my answer is working for you, you can mark as answer. Thank you!